How fix error Object of type *** is not JSON serializable in Airflow?
I make custom library for working with API.
But I get error then trying to use it in my dag.
Then I run my dag I get error for connect_to_api task:
{python.py:202} INFO - Done. Returned value was: [<yclients.yclientsapi object at 0x7f5a0fb87890>]
{xcom.py:664} ERROR - Object of type yclientsapi is not JSON serializable. If you are using pickle instead of JSON for XCom, then you need to enable pickle support for XCom in your airflow config or make sure to decorate your object with attr.
TypeError: Object of type yclientsapi is not JSON serializable

I checked serialization in Airflow documentation, but I don't think I want rewrite my library code.
How I need correct my code to avoid this error?
P. S. I've tried enable pickle support for XCom by adding to docker-compose.yml AIRFLOW__CORE__ENABLE_XCOM_PICKLING=true.
It's not solved my problem.
x-airflow-common: &airflow-common
  #image: apache/airflow:2.8.2
  build: .
  env_file: &airflow-common-env .env
  environment: # delete on error
    - AIRFLOW__CORE__LOAD_EXAMPLES=false # delete on error
    - AIRFLOW__CORE__ENABLE_XCOM_PICKLING=true
  volumes:

Airflow 2.8.2, Python 3.11
Code of my library:
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from datetime import date
import httpx
import ujson

# create class
class yclientsapi:
    def __init__(self, bearer_key: str, user_key: str):
        self.bearer_key = bearer_key
        self.user_key = user_key
        self.headers = {
            "Accept": "application/vnd.yclients.v2+json",
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            'Authorization': f"Bearer {bearer_key}, User {user_key}"
        }
    # get table with salons (stores)
    def get_salons_info(self):
        session = httpx.Client()
        url = "https://api.yclients.com/api/v1/groups"
        response = session.get(url, headers=self.headers)
        first_request=  ujson.loads(response.text)
        df = pd.DataFrame({
            'salon_id': [i['id'] for i in first_request['data'][0]['companies']]
            , 'salon_name': [i['title'] for i in first_request['data'][0]['companies']]
            })
        salon_ids_list = [i['id'] for i in first_request['data'][0]['companies']]
        return df, salon_ids_list

My Dag code:
import datetime
import yclients as yc
from airflow.decorators import dag, task
from airflow.models import Variable
import httpx

default_args = {
    'owner': 'user',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'retries': 2,
    'retry_delay': datetime.timedelta(minutes=5),
    'start_date': datetime.datetime(2024, 6, 20)
}

schedule_interval = '*/20 * * * *'


host = Variable.get('host')
database_name = Variable.get('database_name')
user_name = Variable.get('user_name')
password_for_db = Variable.get('password_for_db')
server_host_name = Variable.get('server_host_name')
bearer_key = Variable.get('bearer_key')
user_key = Variable.get('user_key')
sales_plans_url = Variable.get('sales_plans_url')
specialization_prices_url = Variable.get('specialization_prices_url')
bot_token = Variable.get('bot_token')
chat_id = Variable.get('chat_id')

@dag(default_args=default_args, schedule_interval=schedule_interval, catchup=False, concurrency=4)
def dag_update_database_test():
    @task
    def connect_to_api(bearer_key: str, user_key: str):
        api = yc.yclientsapi(bearer_key, user_key)
        result = []
        result.append(api)
        return result
    
    @task
    def get_salons(api):
        api = api[0]
        result_from_salons_api = api.get_salons_info()
        return result_from_salons_api
       
    @task
    def send_msg(bot_token: str, chat_id: str, message: str):
        message = message[0]
        url = f'https://api.telegram.org/bot{bot_token}/sendMessage?chat_id={chat_id}&text={message}'
        client = httpx.Client()
        client.post(url)

    api_connection_task = connect_to_api(bearer_key=bearer_key, user_key=user_key)
    # get_salon_task[0] = salons_df, get_salon_task[1] = salon_ids_list
    get_salon_task = get_salons(api_connection_task)
    send_test_message = send_msg(bot_token, chat_id, get_salon_task)
    api_connection_task.set_downstream(get_salon_task)
    get_salon_task.set_downstream(send_test_message)
dag_update_database_test = dag_update_database_test()


Is there any reason you want to share the API client object between tasks?
I assume that the basic way of doing something similar is to write your custom code separately from the DAG folder (which you already did), but then wrap it into a class/method with business logic
As a result, you will end up with something like:
my_parser.py
class MyCustomParser:
    def __init__() -> None:
        pass

    def consume_data() -> ...:
        pass

my_notification_service.py
class NotificationService:
    def __init__():
        pass

    def send_message(message) -> ...:
        pass

my_dag.py
from my_parser import MyCustomParser
from my_notification_service import NotificationService

...

def dag_update_database_test():

...

    @task
    def my_scheduled_job() -> None:
        parser_client = MyCustomParser()
        data = parser_client.consume_data()
        notification_client = NotificationService()
        notification_client.send_message(data)

From my point of view, the general idea of XCOM is about passing "metadata" between tasks as lightweight dependencies as parameters/configs

I solved problem by converting pandas.DataFrame to dict:
result = dataframe.to_dict()

And make df from this dict in next @task:
df = pd.DataFrame(dict_with_data)

